# Selenium can not install due to errors

Tags: selenium, command-line, terminal, installation

I am trying to install Selenium and am hitting these errors. I have looked some fixes on Git hub but nothing has helped. Does anyone recognize the issue and have any idea how to fix it?

```
Jasons-MBP:~ jasonmcgriff$ pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
Downloading selenium-2.48.0-py2-none-any.whl (872kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 872kB 421kB/s 
Installing collected packages: selenium
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
root=options.root_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os. py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-   packages/selenium'enter code here
```

Comment: `Permission denied`, it's pretty obvious: you don't have access to `pip`'s installation location. Try running `pip` with elevated status (`sudo` mode). Ex: `sudo pip install selenium`

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is working now.

Comment: This isn't a programming question... it's a support question for Selenium installation.

Comment: @JeffC is the practice of this site to only allow purely programming questions? Questions about the tools used around and for programming are not allowed?

Comment: @JeffC I found this question looking for Selenium tutorials. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331415/selenium-tutorials can you let the know it is not a programming question. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a more detailed description of what kinds of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: Someone got to that question before I did and closed it. :) I see you are new to SO so welcome. As you use the site more you will learn more about what types of questions are acceptable here and which ones are not. If you want to learn about me, click the link to my profile. If you had done that before you started raging you would have seen that Selenium is my top tag so, no, I don't hate Selenium. If you read my profile, you would have also seen that I am an automation engineer and not a programmer.

Comment: I'm trying my best to keep SO clean and useful by following and trying to enforce the guidelines and to provide answers to people's questions where I can. Suggestion... don't take disagreements so hard. It's going to get you banned from SO and make your life miserable. Have a good one.

Comment: @usandfriends would you please post your comment as an answer so Jason can accept it so this question will get marked as answered? Thanks.

Comment: @usandfriends I am not so sure your answer (or comment) is correct. I had this error and can use pip on other libraries. The error is for a specific file and unique issue with Selenium.

Jason John, even though we spend most of our development time on these issues, they don't want them posted here. Hard these days to post a question without being down-voted due to a million opinions how the site should work... I up-voted so you don't have -1 for a well thought out question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last error you posted...

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-   packages/selenium'`

There is something already under `/selenium*`

I had the same issue with this path...

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

By simply deleting like so...

`sudo rm -r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg-info`

Then re-installing it worked and updated to latest. I used this...

`pip install --upgrade selenium`

Notice I did not use sudo or attempt to run as root.